# Using regex to insert hard line breaks to wrap text to a maximum line length, on spaces when possible

Tags: javascript, regex, word-wrap

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out the correct way to code my regex expression. Basically I want to insert hard line breaks (`<br>`) into a string. Let's say I want the maximum line length to be 10 characters. I want to insert a `<br>` at the nearest space before the 11th character, and right before the 11th character if the current line has no spaces within its 10 characters. If the last line has less than 10 characters we do nothing.

Example: `Hello there, my name is Bob` -> `Hello <br>there, my <br>name is <br>Bob`

Example: `HelloThereMyName` -> `HelloThere<br>MyName`

My current regex expression is:

```js
x.replace(/[\s\S]{1,10}(?!\S)/g, '$&<br>')
```

Comment: You can do that with some regex engines, such as PCRE,  Onigmo (used by Ruby), [Python's pypi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex-engine/)  and others that support `\K`, by replacing (zero-length) matches of the regular expression `(?:^(?:.{1,9} |.{10})\K)|\G(?<!^)(?:(?:.{1,9} |.{10})\K)` with `'<br'>`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KggsRi/1). (`\K` resets the start of the match and discards all previously-matched characters.) Hover your cursor over each element of the expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function...

Comment: ...The expression can be modified if the regex engine does not support `\K` but does support variable-length lookbehinds (C++, for example)... I'm not familiar with *typescript* however, so I can't say if it supports `\K` or variable-length lookbehinds.

Comment: Regex may not be the silver bullet for this. 'name is Bob' is 11 characters.

Comment: Hey I changed your question title and description significantly because what you wrote didn't match your input / output examples. It was both wrong because you wrote "insert into nearest space *after* Nth character" when you had to have meant "before" given your examples. Then I simplified the title to what you are really tryihg to do, so more people will find it in searches.

Comment: Also, for your first example, are you sure you want `Hello <br>there, my <br>name is <br>Bob`? Line wrapping usually *replaces* the space with a break, rather than inserts one after. e.g. `Hello<br>there, my<br>name is<br>Bob`. Also what about extra spaces? Can you tell us the expected output for THIS input: `Hello Liz,    my name is Bob.`? I'd think it should be `Hello Liz,<br>my name is<br>Bob.`.

Answer (score 1):

For the example data and desired result, you could either match 10 times any character except a newline followed by a space, or match 10 non whitespace characters.

In the replacement you can use the full match `$&` followed by `<br>`

Note that in your pattern `[\s\S]` matches any character including a newline. Using `(?!\S)` will assert a whitspace boundary to the right, and will not match the last space if there is one.

```
.{1,10} |\S{10}
```

See a [egex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wdXlKg/1)

For example

```js
const regex = /.{1,10} |\S{10}/g;
const str = `Hello there, my name is Bob
HelloThereMyName
nothing
name is Bob`;

console.log(str.replace(regex, `$&<br>`));
```

Comment: This inserts a <br> after the last occurrence of space, even if the length of the string is less than 10 chars

Comment: @mplusr You can get around that by using `.{1,10} (?![ \t]*$)|\S{10}` See https://regex101.com/r/kwaDhN/1